# any idea how to develop Jewel game?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am trying to develop an iphone app in which matrix of jewel. if user alines same type of three or more jewel in a row/column, the lined jewels disappears and other jewels adjusts the space.

Similar to game Call of Atlantis.

Ref : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/146/img1253.png/

Can anybody give me how to begin ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of books on getting started in programming for iPhone.  You should start with one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Geek Game Board](https://bitbucket.org/snej/geekgameboard/). Should get you started.